# How do I install Linux studio plugins?

Tags: sound, software-installation, plugins

Can anyone help me install LSP in the latest version of Ubuntu. Apt get can’t locate the files.

Comment: They're there https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lsp-plugins, not sure what you try to do.

Comment: Thanks, apt get came back negative

Comment: I really want to dump this latest version of Ubuntu, its terrible

Comment: I actually had all the LSP plugins then I upgraded and now theyre gone, how did that happen?

Comment: Can you include relevant error line? Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks, Im just gonna go back to 21.04, this new version woudnt let me install Chrome from the software store, I had to use the command line, same with Spotify

Comment: E: Unable to locate package linux-plugins

Comment: Going back to an about to be out of support release is a huge mistake. The package you want exists for the latest release as well in the universe repository. **Make sure you have universe enabled**. Check Software & Updates.

Comment: I cant seem to locate it,

Comment: I was just getting good with the command line too, lol

Comment: I think it was `lsp-plugins`, have you try installing that ? `sudo apt install lsp-plugins`>

Comment: Thanks Sir, Ill give it a try

Comment: That did it, Thanks so much.